# Iterate array and dictionary together in JavaScript to add values in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, arrays, dictionary

I have an array and a dictionary which adds values in a HTML string in python.
I want to create the HTML string on client side i.e using jQuery or JavaScript.
I can't figure out how to iterate over the array and the dictionary object together in JS or jQuery.

My python code is:

```
 def my_function():
     my_html_string = (('<node name="%(name)s">\n'
                    '<magnitude>%(values)s</magnitude>\n'
                    '%(next_level)s'
                    '</node>\n'
                    ) % {'name': name, 'values': ''.join(["<val>%s</val>" % v
                                                      for v in my_array]),
                     'next_level': '\n'.join(
                     (node.my_function(name) for name, node in my_dict.iteritems()))}
               ).replace('\n\n', '\n')
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal, but it's always important to notice that Python and Javascript will NOT run together. Python will run on server, and spit some string which will be interpreted by the browser - only then, Javascript is run.

Comment: i want to know how i can iterate the array and an object together in javascript. python code is just to show what result i intend to get.